# How to set permissions on SharePoint to hide an aspx page for authenticated users and to make it visible for anonymous users

Tags: 2007, permissions, anonymous-authentication

I have a portal based on a publishing portal. The portal (SPSite) contains has two websites (SPWebs) one is anonymously accessible and other one isn't. This works as expected.

Now I want to set the permissions for some aspx page of the anonymously accessible website so that they are not visible for authenticated users. So it's actually the opposite of anonymous access. User that are not logged in should see the aspx pages and logged in user shouldn't. The aspx pages are normal publishing pages of the publishing portal.

How could I archive this. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this blog post I wrote last week and see if this helps. This doesn't permission the physical file, but you can use this technique to determine if you should show or not show content or a nav link based on the user. http://mike-greene.com/?p=309

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom redirect aspx page which checks if the user is authenticated and does a Server.Transfer("~/Authenticated.aspx") else Server.Transfer("~/Anonymous.aspx")

Comment: Mh, this won't be a solution for me because the single pages will show up in the navigation for both types (authenticated and unauthenticated) users and this is really confusing for the users.

Comment: You can hide the pages from the navigation. Just go to the "Modify Navigation" menu from the site actions, choose those two pages and make them hidden.

Comment: Yes, but to kick both pages out of the navigation won't be a solution either. The visibility of entries in the navigation should depend on the status of the user (authenticated/unauthenticated).